# Crear multiples nuevas columnas de un dataframe aplicando una función propia

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un *dataframe* y hay un momento que quiero hacer una serie de operaciones.

La idea sería esta:

```
def Rx(df):
  O,C,H,L = df['Om'], df['Clas'], df['Has'], df['Lex']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  # 
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  try: R1 = D1/D2
  except ZeroDivisionError: R1 = 1
  print('R1:',R1)
  try: R2 = D1/D3
  except ZeroDivisionError: R2 = 1
  print('R2:',R2)
  try: R3 = D2/D1
  except ZeroDivisionError: R3 = 1
  print('R3:',R3)
  try: R4 = D2/D3
  except ZeroDivisionError: R4 = 1
  print('R4:',R4)
  try: R5 = D3/D1
  except ZeroDivisionError: R5 = 1
  print('R5:',R5)
  try: R6 = D3/D2
  except ZeroDivisionError: R6 = 1
  print('R6:',R6)
  return R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6
```

¿Cómo haría para aplicar esta función sobre mi *dataframe*? He hecho esto (y cosas similares) pero me da error.

```
df.loc[['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6']] = df.apply(Rx, axis=1)
```

Por ahora lo he solucinado creando 6 funciones y llamandolas una a una, pero me parece absurdo teniendo en cuenta el potencial de `Pandas`. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
def R1(df):
  O,C,H,L = df['Om'], df['Clas'], df['Has'], df['Lex']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  # 
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  try: R1 = D1/D2
  except ZeroDivisionError: R1 = 1
  
  return R1

def R2(df):
  O,C,H,L = df['Om'], df['Clas'], df['Has'], df['Lex']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  # 
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  try: R2 = D1/D3
  except ZeroDivisionError: R2 = 1
  
  return R2

def R3(df):
  O,C,H,L = df['Om'], df['Clas'], df['Has'], df['Lex']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  # 
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  try: R3 = D2/D1
  except ZeroDivisionError: R3 = 1
  
  return R3

df['R1'] = df.apply(R1, axis=1)
df['R2'] = df.apply(R2, axis=1)
df['R3'] = df.apply(R3, axis=1)
```

*(Se que podría haber simplificado las funciones ya que hay pasos en común pero este código es solo para salir del paso hasta aprender a hacerlo de la manera que pregunto).*

---

**EDIT a partir de la respuesta de @Abulafia**

Empiezo añadiendo un ejemplo de mi *dataframe* (perdón).

```
    Date        Has         Lex         Om          Clas
0   2020-07-13  4.915115    4.481499    4.613968    4.896294
1   2020-09-22  11.463443   4.125380    4.986754    5.234632
2   2020-09-23  5.342635    3.446731    5.234104    3.521812
3   2020-09-24  4.840724    3.455071    3.521812    4.578369
4   2020-09-25  4.974121    4.235599    4.585006    4.711471
5   2020-09-26  4.815185    4.383511    4.725395    4.541182
6   2020-09-27  4.703974    4.126889    4.538576    4.644225
7   2020-09-28  4.655188    4.203845    4.644225    4.206297
8   2020-09-29  4.289653    3.981965    4.209897    4.142106
9   2020-09-30  4.404218    4.013066    4.142031    4.325939
10  2020-10-01  4.508476    4.054232    4.325457    4.155932
11  2020-10-05  4.047563    3.891379    3.972447    3.992968
12  2020-10-06  4.002682    3.526442    3.991913    3.544228
13  2020-10-07  3.552039    3.234029    3.552039    3.460686
14  2020-10-08  3.949154    3.352270    3.455779    3.909959
15  2020-10-10  4.250989    4.016294    4.241963    4.026705
16  2020-10-11  4.158483    3.970839    4.022435    4.095879
17  2020-10-14  4.485448    4.022536    4.483894    4.150056
18  2020-10-15  4.213541    4.016290    4.152928    4.127353
19  2020-10-16  4.155393    3.887011    4.127866    4.040480
20  2020-10-17  4.196009    3.976694    4.038541    4.196009
21  2020-10-18  4.246367    4.083952    4.192323    4.116062
22  2020-10-19  4.160939    3.997867    4.117765    4.050311
23  2020-10-20  4.081610    3.714379    4.053504    3.802201
24  2020-10-21  4.108505    3.794334    3.800439    3.965959
25  2020-10-22  4.498044    3.962153    3.971725    4.314421
26  2020-10-23  4.486894    4.149672    4.330929    4.262106
27  2020-10-24  4.352660    4.161980    4.262106    4.189700
28  2020-10-25  4.257972    4.105395    4.189700    4.153210
29  2020-10-26  4.479071    4.049678    4.153210    4.160973
```

Si simplemente aplico `result_type="expand"` a mi función `Rx()` me da el siguiente error.

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

En cuanto al tema de la **refactorización** no lo conocía, por lo tanto, ¡Muchas gracias! Era consicente que ese código tenía alguna deficiencia y por eso esa solución de `ZeroDivisionError`, pero no sabía que camino empezar a buscar.

Aún así, si simplemente lo copio, pego y ejecuto me da el siguiente error (el cual es lógico que salga si desconocíais mi *dataframe*).

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'product'.

Me parece super interesante la solución propuesta. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

---

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas te lo da la opción `result_type="expand"` de pandas.

Es decir, harías:

```py
df.loc[:, ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6']] = df.apply(Rx, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

**Edit**. No, no funciona. Lo anterior rellena las nuevas columnas con NaN, no entiendo muy bien por qué. La forma de hacerlo funcionar es concatenar al dataframe original el nuevo dataframe resultante del apply, así:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(Rx, axis=1, result_type="expand")], axis=1)
```

### Bonus: refactorización

En general se desaconseja usar excepciones para hacer "control de flujo". En tu código intentas dividir, y si se produce división por cero asignas 1. En el fondo esto es lo mismo que asignar 1 *si el denominador es 0*, o el cociente en caso contrario. Por tanto podrías hacer una asignación condicional en lugar de los `try/except`.

Así que puedes escribir:

```py
  R1 = 1 if D2==0 else D1/D2
```

en lugar de

```py
  try: R1 = D1/D2
  except ZeroDivisionError: R1 = 1
```

Es más, para evitar tanto código repetitivo, podemos crear estructuras de datos indexadas (diccionarios o listas) y así resolver tu función en un bucle.

Entonces la cosa quedaría así:

```py
def Rx(df):
  P={} 
  O,C,H,L = df['Om'], df['Clas'], df['Has'], df['Lex']
  P[1], P[2], P[3], P[4] = H, O, C, L
  if O>=C: P[2], P[3] = P[3], P[2]

  D = {}
  D[1] = P[1]-P[2]
  D[2] = P[2]-P[3]
  D[3] = P[3]-P[4]

  R = {}
  for name, numer, denom in [("R1", 1, 2), ("R2", 1, 3), ("R3", 2, 1), 
                             ("R4", 2, 3), ("R5", 3, 1), ("R6", 3, 2)]:
      R[name] = 1 if D[denom] == 0 else D[numer]/D[denom]
  return R
```

Fíjate que la función retorna un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de las nuevas columnas que vamos a añadir.

Al aplicar este código a tu dataframe de ejemplo sale:

```html
          Date        Has       Lex        Om      Clas         R1        R2        R3        R4        R5         R6
0   2020-07-13   4.915115  4.481499  4.613968  4.896294  -1.066664  0.726014 -0.937502 -0.680640  1.377384  -1.469206
1   2020-09-22  11.463443  4.125380  4.986754  5.234632 -26.128535  5.838790 -0.038272 -0.223464  0.171268  -4.474992
2   2020-09-23   5.342635  3.446731  5.234104  3.521812  -1.063383  1.018715 -0.940395 -0.957994  0.981629  -1.043848
3   2020-09-24   4.840724  3.455071  3.521812  4.578369  -1.248311  1.174143 -0.801082 -0.940585  0.851685  -1.063168
4   2020-09-25   4.974121  4.235599  4.585006  4.711471  -3.076859  0.817688 -0.325007 -0.265754  1.222960  -3.762875
5   2020-09-26   4.815185  4.383511  4.725395  4.541182  -1.487425  0.801450 -0.672303 -0.538817  1.247738  -1.855917
6   2020-09-27   4.703974  4.126889  4.538576  4.644225  -1.565543  0.319711 -0.638756 -0.204217  3.127825  -4.896743
7   2020-09-28   4.655188  4.203845  4.644225  4.206297  -1.025034  1.019326 -0.975578 -0.994432  0.981040  -1.005599
8   2020-09-29   4.289653  3.981965  4.209897  4.142106  -2.176498  0.647329 -0.459454 -0.297418  1.544809  -3.362275
9   2020-09-30   4.404218  4.013066  4.142031  4.325939  -1.425642  0.837998 -0.701438 -0.587804  1.193320  -1.701247
10  2020-10-01   4.508476  4.054232  4.325457  4.155932  -2.079599  1.299821 -0.480862 -0.625035  0.769337  -1.599912
11  2020-10-05   4.047563  3.891379  3.972447  3.992968  -3.660445  0.739411 -0.273191 -0.202000  1.352428  -4.950490
12  2020-10-06   4.002682  3.526442  3.991913  3.544228  -1.024055  0.984925 -0.976510 -0.961789  1.015306  -1.039729
13  2020-10-07   3.552039  3.234029  3.552039  3.460686  -1.000000  0.287265 -1.000000 -0.287265  3.481112  -3.481112
14  2020-10-08   3.949154  3.352270  3.455779  3.909959  -1.086298  0.884678 -0.920557 -0.814397  1.130355  -1.227903
15  2020-10-10   4.250989  4.016294  4.241963  4.026705  -1.041931  0.993863 -0.959756 -0.953866  1.006175  -1.048365
16  2020-10-11   4.158483  3.970839  4.022435  4.095879  -1.852405  1.088036 -0.539839 -0.587364  0.919087  -1.702522
17  2020-10-14   4.485448  4.022536  4.483894  4.150056  -1.004655  0.726967 -0.995367 -0.723599  1.375578  -1.381982
18  2020-10-15   4.213541  4.016290  4.152928  4.127353  -3.370010  0.630776 -0.296735 -0.187173  1.585348  -5.342639
19  2020-10-16   4.155393  3.887011  4.127866  4.040480  -1.315005  0.477104 -0.760454 -0.362816  2.095977  -2.756220
20  2020-10-17   4.196009  3.976694  4.038541  4.196009  -1.000000  0.717999 -1.000000 -0.717999  1.392759  -1.392759
21  2020-10-18   4.246367  4.083952  4.192323  4.116062  -1.708672  1.202397 -0.585250 -0.703703  0.831672  -1.421054
22  2020-10-19   4.160939  3.997867  4.117765  4.050311  -1.640051  0.922684 -0.609737 -0.562595  1.083794  -1.777478
23  2020-10-20   4.081610  3.714379  4.053504  3.802201  -1.111841  0.823912 -0.899409 -0.741034  1.213723  -1.349467
24  2020-10-21   4.108505  3.794334  3.800439  3.965959  -1.861201  1.794995 -0.537287 -0.964428  0.557105  -1.036884
25  2020-10-22   4.498044  3.962153  3.971725  4.314421  -1.535819  1.494087 -0.651118 -0.972828  0.669305  -1.027931
26  2020-10-23   4.486894  4.149672  4.330929  4.262106  -3.266176  1.240162 -0.306168 -0.379698  0.806346  -2.633669
27  2020-10-24   4.352660  4.161980  4.262106  4.189700  -2.250642  1.627549 -0.444318 -0.723149  0.614421  -1.382841
28  2020-10-25   4.257972  4.105395  4.189700  4.153210  -2.870978  1.242655 -0.348313 -0.432833  0.804729  -2.310359
29  2020-10-26   4.479071  4.049678  4.153210  4.160973 -41.976169  2.927903 -0.023823 -0.069752  0.341541 -14.336597
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! He editado mi pregunta! :)

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, añadiendo un `:` dentro del `.loc[]`. Mira a ver si ahora va (**Edit del comentario**: acabo de ver que has añadido datos de ejemplo, voy a usarlos para depurar y actualizo luego con la respuesta definitiva)

Comment: Eso iba a comentar, faltaban esos `:` para que funcione, jaja. Muchas gracias igualmente por el esfuerzo.

Comment: Arreglado. El valor en `D[x]` no era una Series como había supuesto, sino directamente un flotante, así que más fácil, para compararlo con 0 directamente. Por otro lado he cambiado la función `Rx` para que ahora retorne un diccionario, pues es la forma más simple de que las nuevas columnas se llamen como quieres. Y para añadir las columnas he usado `pd.concat()` en vez de asignación mediante `.loc[]`